# spring boot actuator metrics monitoring with prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have kubernetes cluster with multiple services,
each service has an actuator and an health-check (readiness+liveness probes) 
I tried to create a Prometheus job for one of the services to scrape the response
(200 response indicating service is good), But from my understanding, Prometheus is storing the data as a "time series" key-value so  I'm not sure I am doing it right.
This is the actuator response:

```
{
  "status" : "UP",
  "redisson" : {
    "status" : "UP"
  },
  "jedis" : {
    "status" : "UP",
  }
}
```

And this is my job:

```
  - job_name: 'service'
    scheme: https
    metrics_path: /health
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: service
        namespaces:
          names:
          - default
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
        action: keep
        regex: service
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: service.iot.test.service.co.il:8090
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance                    
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
        target_label: default
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
        target_label: service
```

[image]

Is there a way to scrape the json response that holds the "status"?
And the **"INVALID" is not a valid start token**  is caused by a bad scraping?

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus has a strict [format definition](https://github.com/prometheus/docs/blob/master/content/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats.md). A quick solution would be just to change the endpoint to whatever is defined in springboot app (/actuator/prometheus or so). And check the metric "up" which is generated by prometheus for each [target](https://www.robustperception.io/alerting-on-down-instances). 
I haven't tried Prometheus operator yet. so I cannot advise on that.